# I need to calculate the sum of columns in an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have a two-dimensional array, the cells are an object {id, amount}, you need to add a sum of columns, while using only methods. What I did -

```
let matrix = [
    [{id:1, amount:11},{id:2, amount:22},{id:3, amount:33}],
    [{id:4, amount:44},{id:5, amount:55},{id:6, amount:66}],
    [{id:7, amount:77},{id:8, amount:88},{id:9, amount:99}],
    [{id:10, amount:100},{id:11, amount:111},{id:12, amount:112}],
];

let c = matrix.reduce((acc, cur)=> {
    return acc.map((item, index)=> {
        return item + cur[index].amount;
    })
});
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: Yup, it's actually quite unclear! I think everyone didn't understand the same thing.

Comment: output value: ["[object Object]4477100", "[object Object]5588111", "[object Object]6699112"]
but need: [232, 276, 310]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `flatMap` then `reduce`?

```js
let matrix = [
        [{id:1, amount:11},{id:2, amount:22},{id:3, amount:33}],
        [{id:4, amount:44},{id:5, amount:55},{id:6, amount:66}],
        [{id:7, amount:77},{id:8, amount:88},{id:9, amount:99}],
        [{id:10, amount:100},{id:11, amount:111},{id:12, amount:112}],
    ];
let result = matrix.flatMap(it => it).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.amount, 0);
console.log(result)
```

**EDIT**

After getting what you actually wanted to do, here is a complement (feel free not to read above).

```js
const matrix = [
        [{id:1, amount:11},{id:2, amount:22},{id:3, amount:33}],
        [{id:4, amount:44},{id:5, amount:55},{id:6, amount:66}],
        [{id:7, amount:77},{id:8, amount:88},{id:9, amount:99}],
        [{id:10, amount:100},{id:11, amount:111},{id:12, amount:112}],
    ];
    
let result = matrix
             .flatMap(it => it) //This flattens the items.
             .reduce((acc, item, i) => (acc[i%matrix[0].length] += item.amount, acc), //This computes the sum based on the indices and the matrix width.
             Array.apply(0, Array(matrix[0].length)).map(_ => 0)); //This inits the result array with zeros.

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I need an array of each column amount, example [232, 276, 310]

Comment: @ЖеняБорісевіч another piece of code ;) You tell me if you like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of length equal to width of array. Then use nested `forEach` to add the values to corresponding element.

```js
let matrix = [
        [{id:1, amount:11},{id:2, amount:22},{id:3, amount:33}],
        [{id:4, amount:44},{id:5, amount:55},{id:6, amount:66}],
        [{id:7, amount:77},{id:8, amount:88},{id:9, amount:99}],
        [{id:10, amount:100},{id:11, amount:111},{id:12, amount:112}],
    ];

let res = Array(matrix[0].length).fill(0)
matrix.forEach(x => {
  x.forEach((y,i) => {
    res[i] += y.amount;
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: possible without using for, foreach

Answer (score 0):

So decided, if there are better solutions, I will be glad to see

```
getColSumMatrix = matrix =>
    matrix.reduce((acc, cur) =>
      acc.map((value, i) =>
        typeof value == "object"
          ? value.amount + cur[i].amount
          : value + cur[i].amount
      )
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const summ = matrix.reduce((acc, table) => {
        return (
            acc +
            table.reduce((acc, { amount }) => {
                return acc + amount;
            }, 0)
        );
    }, 0);
```

Comment: I need an array of each column amount, example [232, 276, 310]